# Flex 4 - How to draw a shape to use as a skin for a ButtonBarButton

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, drawing, skin, buttonbar

I'm using Flash Builder 4 and am in the process of learning.

The short and simple explanation is, I want a tab navigator that has tabs that look like this:

[image: First Tab][image: Middle Tabs]

I know I could do this using an image-based skin, but I figured (and could be wrong) that programmatically drawing the shape would be better in terms of scalability.

As long as I get the result I'm looking for, I guess I don't really care if it's mx or spark. I tried doing this:

**Main App:**

```
<mx:ButtonBar dataProvider="{vsTabNav}" firstButtonStyle="firstButtonStyle"/>
```

**CSS File:**

```
.firstButtonStyle { skinClass:ClassReference("assets.skins.ButtonBarFirstButtonSkin"); }
```

**ButtonBarFirstButtonSkin.as:**

```
package assets.skins
{
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import mx.skins.halo.ButtonBarButtonSkin;
    import mx.graphics.RectangularDropShadow;

    public class ButtonBarFirstButtonSkin extends ButtonBarButtonSkin
    {
        private var dropShadow:RectangularDropShadow;

        public function ButtonBarFirstButtonSkin()
        {
            super();
        }

        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void 
        {
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

            var cornerRadius:Number = getStyle("cornerRadius");
            var backgroundColor:int = getStyle("backgroundColor");
            var backgroundAlpha:Number = getStyle("backgroundAlpha");
            graphics.clear();

            cornerRadius = 10;
            backgroundColor = 0xFF0000;
            backgroundAlpha = 1;

            // Background
            drawRoundRect(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight, {tl:1, tr:cornerRadius, bl:1, br:1}, backgroundColor, backgroundAlpha);

            // Shadow
            if (!dropShadow)
                dropShadow = new RectangularDropShadow();

            dropShadow.distance = 8;
            dropShadow.angle = 45;
            dropShadow.color = 0;
            dropShadow.alpha = 0.4;
            dropShadow.tlRadius = 1;
            dropShadow.trRadius = cornerRadius;
            dropShadow.blRadius = 1;
            dropShadow.brRadius = 1;
            dropShadow.drawShadow(graphics, 0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        }

    }
}
```

This should mean that the first button will be red and will have a very round top-right corner. Instead, I just get the default button. Not sure what I'm doing wrong there, but if that's not the best solution, I would love some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, have a look at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex4_skinning.html

Then, you should realize, you'll be better off creating first skins for your ButtonBarButtons and make sure your button bar uses them for its buttons.

Also, you can create the shapes with the Path class. Following is an example that creates similar shapes to yours:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <s:Path x="10" y="10"
            data="M 0 2 V 18 H 200 Q 190 3 170 0 H 2 L 0 2 Z" 
            width="200" height="20"  >
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFDFDFD" ratio="0.6" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x8A8A8A" ratio="1" />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke color="0x000000" />
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Path>

    <s:Path x="215" y="10"
            data="M 30 0 Q 10 0 0 20 H 200 Q 190 3 170 0 H 30 Z" 
            width="200" height="20"  >
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x8f8f8f" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x878787" ratio="0.6" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x5d5d5d" ratio="1" />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke color="0x000000" />
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Path>
</s:Application>
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want scaling, you can put the Path element into a Graphic element, and setup its scaleGrid properties:

```
<s:Graphic scaleGridTop="1" scaleGridBottom="19" scaleGridLeft="10" scaleGridRight="170"
           width="150" height="15"
           x="10" y="10" 
           >
    <s:Path 
            data="M 0 2 V 18 H 200 Q 190 3 170 0 H 2 L 0 2 Z" 
            width="200" height="20" >
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFDFDFD" ratio="0.6" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0x8A8A8A" ratio="1" />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke color="0x000000" />
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Path>
</s:Graphic>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I wasn't aware of  `s:Path`. I thought I had to use Actionscript to draw an irregular shape. And a special thanks for doing all the work for me :-)

Comment: Is there a way for me to specify scaling regions for this, so that the curved part stretches vertically, but not horizontally?

Comment: Thanks again. I figured it out a while after my last comment, I did the same thing, but I just used a `s:Group` with scaleGrid settings.

Answer (score 0):

If that is all you want to achieve - can't you just specify the corner radius values in the CSS style and move on (without a custom skin)?

:)

Comment: How do I make the bottom corners pointed, like in the images in the original post, with corner radius?

Comment: cornerRadius:10;
focusRoundedCorners:tr;  (only round one corner)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help me with the acute angle on the bottom corner(s).